# Getting the children of a transform skips every other child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wish to get the children of the children of my `gameObject`. I'm not talking about recursion, I just have a `Whole`, under which have many `Segment`s, and every segment has a couple of `Tile`s in them like so:

[image]

The goal is to get those tiles into one collection and then parent them under the given gameobject.

To do so, I do this:

```
foreach (Transform child in whole.transform)
{ 
    foreach (Transform tile in child)
    {
        //even with the following line commented out it's the same. 
        tiles.AddElement(tile.GetComponent<Tile>());
        tile.SetParent(transform);
    }
}
```

which is pretty straightforward, except it doesn't work. It throws no exceptions, and fetches every other child like so:

[image]

The code is very basic and definitely should work. Those `tile` prefabs are identical, no difference between them except for their location maybe.

Edit: and all the objects I operate on are active. Even after this setup, I find the skipped tiles right where they were left, all of them are active. In debug mode I see the `ChildCount` is 5. I step through the loops, and it just skips every other child.

EDIT AGAIN:

I have a hunch it's a Unity bug.

[image]

Now my `i` is **1**, which is the second index as we all know it. And it returns the third tile, `tile (2)` (they are tile, tile (1) and tile (2) in this order).

Guess who files a bug report.

Comment: You're right, `The code is very basic and definitely should work`. There's probably something else. What does AddElement do? Have you tried setting a counter in the loop and seeing if it actually loops through them all? EDIT: Just saw your edit. That's super weird and you should probably file a bug report for Unity.

Comment: Not yet, I go ahead and try that. `AddElement` is an element of a custom data structure of mine, derived from `List<>`, but I commented out that line for testing, and got the same results. 
I check the `GetChild(int)` version now.

Comment: which version are you rocking?

Comment: 2017.3.0p3. I'm trying what you mentioned in the answer, checking if it does what it should :D

Comment: Really weird, it works nicely for me in 2017.3.0f3 with the nested foreaches. a game object with 5 game objects in, with 5 game objects each in and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @your latest edit, you're sure theres nothing happening in any other script that's messing with it? You haven't attached the script on something else?

Comment: lol. I'll try to un-nest the loops, and include a temporary collection, maybe it solves it

Comment: No, only one gameobject uses this script I'm calling the loops in, and I'm not doing anything parallel.

Comment: You know there are many child gameobjects. What's the names of the ones you want to move? "tile? "trackpiece"?

Comment: The `tile` ones. They are parented under the `trackpiece` because their Z order (which is first, second etc) will be randomized later on. Right now I'm not doing any of that, I just need all `tile` gameobjects under my `trackRB`

Comment: Ok. Each Tile object has `Tile` component attached to it, right? What about `trackpiece`? Do they have Tile` component attached to them too? Just making sure I get some details before adding answer. Finally, the `whole` variables refers to the WholeTrack GameObject?

Comment: No, the trackpieces have no Tile components but **every** tile has a `Tile` component (they are unchanged prefabs). They have a currently empty `TrackSegment` class on them only. By the way the `GetComponent<Tile>()` part was commented out and I got the same result. Yes, the `whole` is the WholeTrack go. Sorry for the late reps, got hasty :(

Comment: @Programmer did I answer all you needed? I edited the comment multiple times.

Comment: Yes. I know the issue but just verifying the code before posting. I like working codes in my answers. Check back in a moment

Comment: Okay thanks, I wait a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to remove the Object in the `for` loop while accessing them. That's the issue.

Here is what you should do:

**1**.Find all Child objects and store them in `List`

**2**.You can now destroy or move them into another GameObject by looping over the `List` from **#1**.

```
public GameObject whole;
public GameObject TrackRb;

public void moveChildren()
{
    int i = 0;

    //List to hold all child obj
    List<Transform> allChildren = new List<Transform>();

    //Find all child obj and store to that List
    foreach (Transform child in whole.transform)
    {
        foreach (Transform tile in child)
        {
            //Make sure the Tile component is attached to the child before using it
            if (tile.GetComponent<Tile>() != null)
            {
                allChildren.Add(tile);
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //Now Move them into the TrackRb
    foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
    {
        child.SetParent(TrackRb.transform);
    }

    Debug.Log(i);
}
```

If you destroy or move the object while still looking for it, *it changes position in the hierarchy*. So your next loop might have a null object in it, skip some objects or even have a wrong object in the next loop. That's why you get all the objects first then moving them under another Object as a child.

Comment: And it works flawlessly. I had a hinch destroying would cause an issue but I'd never know moving too. Thanks for the answer! Guess who doesn't file a bug report after all...

Comment: Yup they are basically the-same thing in this case since they will be moved away from the current parent `transform` therefore messing up the loop. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write in comments but the formatting just gets too messy when including code.

If ChildCount gives you 5 but it doesn't loop through them correctly in the foreach it kind of sounds like a Unity bug. As a workaround I guess you could try to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tran.childCount; i++) {
    tran.GetChild(i);
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, the index 1 (second) returns the third tile :D but for no apparent reason the outer loop works fine xd

Answer (score 0):

for(int i = child.Childcount - 1; i > -1; i--)

Reverse the order of the for loop.